# Disable single button of buttongroup - extjs

Tags: extjs4, disabled-control, buttongroup

I am having button group in which I am having 4 buttons...I want to disable particular button on some button click.. how can i do this?

I have tried :

```
    buttonItemID.disabled = true.  (radarbutton.disabled = true)
```

but cant get result.

please give me solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button#buttonItemID')[0].disable();
```

Comment: i have done the same  this.getBookGridViewsRadar().clickable=true;

Comment: bookgridviewsradar is reference of bottonID

Comment: then use the disable method this.getBookGridViewsRadar().disable()

Comment: Maybe i didn't understand exactly the issue, you have issues disabling it on some button click?

Comment: no..i am having 1 combobox...On selecting particular items i want to disable , one particular button from buttongroup